# Rails create or update for associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have this example code which raises a "Duplicate Expection". Instead, I want just to skip if a duplicate exists.

```
(1..10).each do |page|
      group.products << [{id: 1, title: "Example A"}, {id: 2, title: "Example B"}]
      group.save
end
```

The product array is static just for this example, what matter is that it has ID's, so products exist in the database.

The problem is when I assign a product that I have already assigned in the past which raise a "Not Unique exception". In this scenario, I would just skip the association. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `create_with` in combination with `find_or_create_by`:

```
(1..10).each do |page|
  group.products << Product.create_with(title: "Example A").find_or_create_by(id: 1)
  group.products << Product.create_with(title: "Example B").find_or_create_by(id: 2)
  group.save
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the same dynamic array of objects to `group.products` in a ten times loop which is creating duplicates. Why are you not running this without a loop? I don't think so there is a need for a loop.

Comment: OP doesn't want to skip the validation but a solution to avoid adding duplicate records

Answer (score 0):

Other option could be to use `first_or_initialize`:

```
(1..10).each do |page|
  group.products << Product.where(id: 1).first_or_initialize(title: "Example A").save
  group.products << Product.where(id: 2).first_or_initialize(title: "Example B").save
  group.save
end
```